# How log to the Output window with ASP.Net vNext/5

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

Using Visual Studio 2015 RC and ASP.Net vNext/5 beta4.
I would like to output logging to the Output Window in Visual Studio when debugging or, if possible, to the console window hosting the site when using the WebListener. My Web project is built on the standard out of the box template for a Web app so has most of the default stuff in there.

In my `Startup` I have the usual default

```
loggerfactory.AddConsole();
```

In my controller I inject ILoggerFactory and do something like this;

```
this.logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<ThingClass>();
this.logger.LogVerbose("Verbose");
this.logger.LogInformation("Info");
this.logger.LogError("error");
```

None of that gets written out to the Debug window or elsewhere - I am not really sure what `AddConsole()` is supposed to achieve here?

I then tried to add `Microsoft.Framework.Logging.TraceSource` to `project.json` and

```
loggerfactory.AddTraceSource(new SourceSwitch("web-app", "Verbose"), new DefaultTraceListener());
```

to `Startup`. That actually works - except now every log message gets written *twice* to the console, which is rather annoying.

I am clearly missing something fundamental here but cannot find any documentation on the new Microsoft.Framework.Logging. In fact, the most comprehensive and in-depth documentation I have been able to track down is Nicholas Blumhardt's short article here: http://nblumhardt.com/2015/05/diagnostic-logging-in-dnx-asp-net-5/.

I *do* understand that the framework is supposed to just be a wrapper and that I can implement my own providers as well use a range of frameworks like Serilog etc. But... for a simple application surely I should be able to log to the debug window in VS without a lot of ceremony?

Comment: good coverage here http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/logging-in-the-owin-world-with-microsoft-owin--introduction

Comment: @JJS thanks, that is interesting! It looks like it is about the equivalent in OWIN, rather than vNext/5. But, I am sure there are things I may be able to extrapolate from one to the other, as the new one is likely to have evolved from that one, so thank you :)

Comment: vNext/5 uses OWIN. They're not entirely different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're adding a debug logger in beta6 https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Debug

Update:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug/1.0.0-rc1-final

Comment: To elaborate a bit -- simply adding loggerFactory.AddDebug(LogLevel.Information); in Configure() of Startup.cs will allow you to see EF generated sql statements in the Visual Studio Debug Output.  Thanks davidfowl!